# ASP.NET Gridview - How do I change the color properties vertically?

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, vb.net, gridview

I have a dynamic gridview, about 35 rows by 11 columns. When the user hovers over a row, I highlight the row's background in green (with CSS:Hover).

I would like to change the column's background as well, but I don't think I can assign css to a entire column. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how is done, step-by-step: http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/